# How Nodejs EventEmitter.once() work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From the nodejs [source code (LOC 179)](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/ed0d1c384cd4578f7168633c838f1252bddb260e/lib/events.js#L190-L209), we have the following:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.once = function(type, listener) {

  /** ... **/

  function g() { /** ... **/ }

  g.listener = listener; // => ???
  this.on(type, g);

  return this;
};
```

So far, my thinking goes like this:

`EventEmitter.once()` sets an event of `type` and removes it immediately once the callback `listener` has been called via the `g()`. But what really does the line `g.listener = listener;` do?

Does it add a property `listener` which is a function to the function object created by the constructor `g()` at the time of invocation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is set so that you can later call `removeListener`.

If you call `this.once(event, listener)` and later call `this.removeListener(listener)`, the code will not find `listener` in the list because it is wrapped inside `g`.

That's why the test at [L214](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/ed0d1c384cd4578f7168633c838f1252bddb260e/lib/events.js#L226-L227) does:

```
 if (list === listener ||
      (util.isFunction(list.listener) && list.listener === listener)) {
```